# Bring back pixelation! (a how-to)

Tags: discussion, design

[Here's a user CSS file by myself to bring more pixelation awesomeness to Gaming.](http://gist.github.com/614745)

Chrome users can enjoy it with [Personalized Web](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/plcnnpdmhobdfbponjpedobekiogmbco), use the following as the match URL:

```
^http://(meta\.)?gaming\.stackexchange\.com/.*
```

There is a similar extension for Firefox and a built in tool for Opera users.

This released under the WTFPL license. I'm using it myself, so I'll amend it as I see new defects.

I applied the pixel font for pretty much everything except text. Only sizes of 8px, 16px and 24px are used for it, however. The bonus portion removes traces of Tahoma, bringing the design down to two fonts: Tempesta and Arial.

**(new)** Affect the new user dropdown. Add subtle, delicious <s>bling</s> glow. Change suggested edits counter to blue.

[image: Glow in action.]

#### Screenshots: [homepage](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Skin/Homepage.png) - [question page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Skin/Question.png) - [editing questions](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Skin/Editing.png) - [profile page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Skin/Profile.png) - [recent activity](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Skin/Recent.png) - [revisions](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Skin/Revisions)

Here's the smallest of the full page screenshots:

[image: link text]

Comment: Is that supposed to be "(a how-to)", as in "This is a how-to for bringing it back", or "(and how-to)", as in "Bring it back, and this is how-to!"?

Comment: @Grace The former, since there was much hate towards the font. If people say "hey this doesn't totally suck" when looking at the screenshots I can consider posting the latter, though ;)

Comment: The question colour leak around in the screenshot. I blame the full-page screenshotting utility :/

Comment: Can you add header files for Greasemonkey so it will work in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE?

Comment: @ArdaXi it isn't that simple -- I merely patched up the CSS. I didn't write the javascript that injects it into the page, however.

Comment: @badp Stylish maybe?

Comment: @Arda Or [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha).

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of collaboration, I made a minified version that works wherever Greasemonkey does, ie. Chrome, Opera and Firefox. The gist is on [Github](https://gist.github.com/826250), if you want to see the source.

[Install](https://gist.github.com/raw/826250/get_back_pixelation.user.js).